# Set the list separator in Mac

Tags: excel, macos, separator, regional-settings

In Windows, **List separator** (`,` as shown in my system) is a parameter that we could set:

[image]

I'm trying to find this setting in my Mac, but I could not find it. Here is the only thing I could find:

[image]

It seems that this separator is used to separate arguments in Excel functions.

Does anyone know how to set the list separator in Mac?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/447492/738512

Comment: @SolarMike It is not the same question.

Comment: Well, I use excel and "," and ":" work fine - as long as you know how to use the functions.

Comment: See [What can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question seems unrelated to programming.

Comment: What Mac OS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS Big Sur 11.4

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an exact solution, but may get you to where you want to be.

You can force Excel to use your preferred list seperator instead of the system / regional settings one.

In Excel:
Options, Advanced, un-check "Use System separators".

Comment: Then, where could we set the separator in Excel for Mac?

Comment: There is a field right under that check box in the Excel settings, to set your own separator. Not sure if field looks the same on latest mac version of Excel or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution because I have the same issue:

Goto, setting>Language&region> General, then select English(US) as your primary language, after you have to reset your computer.

[image: Language and region screen]

Also, you need to check in: setting>Language&region> App, that Excel the system default is English - English

[image: Language and region screen for Excel]